# Get content and status code from HttpResponse

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, fluent

I am using apache's HttpClient (via the Fluent API). When I get the response object back, I first do:

```
response.returnResponse().getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

If status code is 4xx or 5xx, I throw an exception, or I return the content:

```
response.returnContent().asBytes();
```

The `response` here is an object of type `Response`. But when I run this, I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response content has been already consumed.
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: What type is `response`?

Comment: `response` is of type `Response` which is returned by `request.execute()`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both `Response#returnResponse()` and `Response#returnContent()` force the `HttpResponse` `InputStream` to be read. Since you can't read the `InputStream` twice, the library has put flag and a check to assert that the `InputStream` hasn't been consumed.

You don't get around this. What you do is get the underlying `HttpResponse` object and get both the status code and the body as bytes.

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = response.returnResponse();
httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(httpResponse.getEntity());
```